# Windows 7 64-bit. Fresh install on fresh PC fails with BSOD

Tags: windows-7, troubleshooting, installation, bsod

I've built a new machine:

```
Asus M4A785TD-V EVO
OCZ DDR3 PC3-12800 (2x 2GB)
AMD Athlon II X4 630 Box AM3
```

I tried memtest with hiren boot CD (tested only 3GB) and showed no error. Then I tried the built in RAM test from the Windows 7 CD (2 passes no errors). I also deleted with a 0 pass the hard drive. The error I get is this:

```
0x0000007e (0xFFFFFFFFFC0000005,0xFFFFF8000C1AB0F3,0xFFFFF880009A8498,0xFFFFF880009A7CF0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your Event Viewer to see if any devices are causing errors. Common causes of that error include hardware incompatibility or faulty drivers, as well as sleep issues. Did you have to install any additional drivers to get something working? Any legacy software added?

Comment: Now I've been able to install win7 with the safe mode, I ran it the whole day, now I've rebooted and I'm greeted with this: SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION. Safe Mode works greatly.